# Кратность значений в input

Tags: php, cms, javascript

Добрый день. Может кто знает как сделать автоматическое округление введенных значений в input с выведением сообщения о том что значение изменено. Данная функция необходима для изменения значений кол-ва товаров в корзине, чтобы было не любое число которое вводит пользователь, а кратное кол-ву товаров в упаковке. Кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение с jQuery. Могу написать и без нее.

```
<input type="text" pack="4" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[pack]').change(function(){ // вешаем обработчик на все инпуты с атрибутом pack
    var val = ~~this.value || 0; // получаем значение
    var pack = ~~this.getAttribute('pack') || 0; // получаем кол-во в упаковке
    if(val%pack != 0){
        this.value = val - val%pack; // уменьшаем кол-во
        // или увеличиваем - this.value = Math.ceil(val/pack)*pack;
        alert('Значение изменено кратно кол-ву в упаковке!');
    }
});
</script>
```

**Обновил код**
Теперь скрипт работает так: задаете инпуту атрибут pack - кол-во в упаковке и... все. =) И работает.

**Добавка**
Если нужна совместимость с другой библиотекой, можно также дописать `var j = jQuery.noConflict();` и использовать j(...) вместо $(...) либо же сразу писать jQuery(...) вместо $(...) .

Comment: Пришел Линг и все испортил: теперь соберет все плюсы и уйдет%).
Слухай, что такое ~~?

Comment: И еще. Лучше увеличивать число, чем уменьшать. Если у меня прибор жрет 3 батарейки, мне не имеет смысл предлагать две.

Comment: **~~** - дважды побитовая инверсия. Можно применять вместо parseInt, так как работает быстрее. Единственное отличие - не возвращает NaN, поэтому приходится делать **|| 0**;  
Спс, ща допишу. =)

Comment: Пользователь вводит количество, уходит с инпута - и тут количество меняется и выскакивает окошко с руганью.  
`var val = ~~this.value || 0;` - это просто получение значения инпута и приведение его к целому числу. А то бывают индивиды, которые пишут числа буквами.

Comment: это ковычки экранирую слешем. они тут видимо заменяются
ошибки выдавал когда я сразу после input хотел вставить. перенес после создания всех инпутов и ошибок нет

Comment: в итоге правильный ответ:
$html .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
        $html .= "var j = jQuery.noConflict(); j('input[pack]').change(function(){"; 
        $html .= "var val = ~~this.value || 0;"; 
        $html .= "var pack = ~~this.getAttribute('pack') || 0;";
        $html .= "if(val%pack != 0){";
        $html .= "this.value = Math.ceil(val/pack)*pack;";
        $html .= "alert('Значение изменено кратно кол-ву в упаковке!'); } }); </script>";
тут он вместе с php? но думаю понятно) СПАСИБО ling!

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <script>
        function pri() {
            var t=10;
            if (t%2 != 1){
                alert('тест');
            }
        }
    </script>
    <form action=# method=post>
        <input type="text" onchange="pri();">
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var quantity_per_pack = 5; //Число продуктов в упаковке
var amount = Math.ceil($('input#user_amount').val()/quantity_per_pack)*quantity_per_pack;
$('input#user_amount').val(amount);
alert('Значение изменено, чтобы соответствовать целому числу упаковок.');
```

Comment: var quantity_per_pack = 5; //Число продуктов в упаковке

определяется по переменной. у каждого товара свое значение, разное кол-во в упаковке.

Comment: Вместо пяти подставляете нужное количество. Можете подставлять динамически, запихав этот текст в .change()