# Плагин jquery. Создание нового метода для элемента.

Tags: jquery

Народ, признаюсь честно: я ничегошеньки не понял в создании плагинов к jquery. мне стыдно, но надо исправляться. В теме [кратность-значений-в-input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32766/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-input) я создал внутренности метода для изменения инпута. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ЭТО превратить в

```
$("SELECTOR").correct_value(quantity_per_pack);
```

Чтобы работало с любым инпутом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите [ссылку](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/67.html), разберите пару плагинов. Если окажется мало, я попробую расписать подробнее. =)

**Добавлено**

```
<p class="myFuncted">eeeee</p>
<p>eeeee</p>
<p class="myFuncted">eeeee</p>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.fn.myFunction = function(options){ // пишем через jQuery, чтобы можно было переопределить через noConflict()
    var opts = jQuery.extend({
        // тут идут значения по умолчанию
        // если в объекте options что-то не было передано, оно подтянется из этого объекта
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2'
    }, options); // ок, объединили значения объектов. все теперь хранится в объекте opts
    return this.each(function(){ // бежим по всем элементам выборки jQuery
        // а тут идет код плагина
        // this - конкретный элемент, с которым работаем
        // opts мы заранее сформировали со всеми необходимыми параметрами
        var t = $(this);
        t.data('params', opts.param1+' '+opts.param2);
    }); // return нужен для совместимости
};

$('.myFuncted').myFunction({param1: 'value_not_1'}).css('color', 'red').click(function(){alert($(this).data('params'));});
// вызов плагина. из-за return this.each можно применять эффекты в цепочке
</script>
```

**Добавлено еще**
1) Через $ работать тоже будет. Но для совместимости с другими библиотеками лучше использовать jQuery ($ - это псевдоним, его можно переопределить).
2) `var opts = jQuery.extend(defObj, options);` Из defObj jQuery сама перетягивает пары ключ:значение в options, если таких ключей нет в options. Доступ к свойствам opts осуществляется через opts.param или opts['param'].
3) options задается при вызове функции, а defObj пишется разработчиком. Все параметры являются необязательными, но если без каких-то из них ваш плагин не будет работать, их придется задать в defObj.

Comment: 1) пишем через jQuery// через $ тоже будет работать? Почему не наоборот?
2) оно подтянется из этого объекта - в каком виде? Например, аттрибут value - opts.val() или this.val()?
3) как указать, что параметр обязательный/не обязательный? Аналог в PHP: function myfunc($var1,$var2='abc'); var2 - необязательный параметр.
Или стандартными яваскриптовыми методами через arguments?

Comment: Еще добавлено.