# Javascript функция

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Привет всем!

Хотелось бы узнать кое-что у специалистов `javascript`. Например, в `javascript`-файле есть написанная функция:

```
function Func () {
... code
}
```

и она вызывается так `Func()`;
или так, ну примерно:

```
$('#sometag').click( function () {
    Func();
})
```

или в `html`:

```
<h5 ocnlick="Func()">aa </h5>
```

А некоторые разработчики плагинов делают так, чтобы функция вызывалась вот так:

```
$('#sometag').func();
```

Как написать функцию или что сделать, чтобы функция `javascript` вызывалась так же?

Comment: @mixail, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Написал вот такой мощный плагин:

(function ($) {
 $.fn.plag = function () {
 alert('hello');
 };
})(Jquery); 
который вызывается так
$('#plag').plag();

но он не работает почему-то. Кто знает, почему?

Comment: Ваш код:

    (function ($) { $.fn.plag = function () { alert('hello'); }; })(Jquery);

Правильный код:

    (function ($) { $.fn.plag = function () { alert('hello'); }; })(jQuery);

Найдите пять отличий.

Comment: аааааааа   СПС!! все заработало !

Answer (score 1):

> а некоторые разработчики плагинов делают так, чтобы фукция вызывалась вот так $('#sometag').func(); Как написать функцию или что сделать, чтобы функция яваскрипт вызывалась так же?

Чтобы Ваша функция вызывалась так же, Вам необходимо написать свой jQuery-плагин. О том, как это делается, можно легко найти в гугле по запросу "custom jquery plugin". Однако перед тем как писать свой jquery-плагин, Вам лучше определиться с тем, что вы в действительности хотите.

**P.S.**

> Func () { ... code } и она вызывается так Func();

Объявление функция таким образом (первая буква в верхнем регистре) рекомендуется делать, если Вы планируете вызывать данную функция как конструктор:

```
function Func(){};
var foo = new Func();
```

Иначе, в Вашем случае, объявляйте название функции с маленькой буквы:

```
function func(){};
func();
```

Answer (score 0):

[плагин jquery создание нового метода для элемента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/32775/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-jquery-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)

Вот здесь очень подробно и хорошо описано.